# What is the most efficient way to hide rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have written this script that should run every night, however the problem is that it takes too long to execute so the server shuts it down. We have a spreadsheet that we use as a calendar to organise our school production and we'd like it to automatically hide days that have passed. I wrote this script about 8 months ago and it took me about 6-7 hours to get it to work and it worked for a bit before we got far enough down the spreadsheet that it takes too long. Here is the script:

```
function hidePastDays(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("OVERVIEW");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("settings");
  var rows = s.getMaxRows();
  var today = s2.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  s.showRows(1, rows);
  var dates = s2.getRange(3,4,rows-2).getValues();
  for (var d=0; d < dates.length; d++){
    if (dates[d]<today-2){
      s.hideRows(d+3, 1);
      for (var g in allsheets){
        var sheet=allsheets[g];
        if (sheet.getSheetName() == "OVERVIEW" || sheet.getSheetName() == "settings"){}
        else {
          sheet.hideRows(d+3, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was thinking it must be easier to just scan down to the correct row and then hide all of them as a range because I think script does it one at a time.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are the rows in order by date?  If the code finds the row with the first current date, would if work if the code hid all the rows from 3 to that row minus 1 row?  That could be done in one operation instead of hiding one by one.

Comment: Yes they are. The dates are automatically added by the spreadsheet. However it would need to find the current date and then move back a row because if multiple activities are on the same day the dates aren't repeated the date section is just left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a routine that looks for the row range that represents days older than yesterday.  It hides all of them at one time which I'm guessing is a lot faster than doing it one at a time.  Of course this assumes that you can get all the dates in date order.

```
function hideYesterdays()
{
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var drng = sht.getDataRange();
  var drngA = drng.getValues();
  var rows = drng.getLastRow();
  var firstRow = 6; //the row where dates start
  var day = 86400000;
  var yesterday = new Date().getTime() - day;// 1 day is 86400000 milliseconds

  var rowcntr = 0;
  while(drngA[rowcntr + firstRow][0] < yesterday) //the zero comes from the fact that my dates were in row 1. 
  {
    rowcntr++;
  }
  sht.hideRows(firstRow, rowcntr);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is a big help. The dates are all in order however if multiple activities are on one day it will just add a blank row with no date (because it is written in the row above). So I needed to modify your formula a little bit by changing `var rowcntr = 0;` to `var rowcntr = -1;` which gives me two previous days which is actually what I wanted. :)

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in my previous comment. I had to double the `day` value as well to have two previous days.

Comment: Sounds like you have a handle on the problem.  Have fun.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented it already and it's so nice to have it working again (otherwise we need to manually hide rows on 10 sheets).